# Grouping two records in a single record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following records: 
I want to retrieve the records as:

```
Jonh | 2019-07-17 07:19:24.00 | 2019-07-17 08:15:24.00 | 55
```

I want to fetch for each adjacents ins and outs of the employee and calculate the number of hours worked for each slot.

```
  ID  |Name  |IO        |TimeIn                  |TimeOut                      | Hours Worked
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    11  |Jonh    |0         |2019-07-17 07:19:24.000 |                         |
    11  |Jonh    |1         |                        |2019-07-17 08:15:24.000  |
    11  |Jonh    |0         |2019-07-17 08:39:42.000 |                         |
    11  |Jonh    |1         |                        |  2019-07-17 17:25:22.000|
```

What I have done here only fetches the first in and last out:

```
select id_emp, name, date,
       min(case when inorout = 0 then timecol end) as timein,
       max(case when inorout = 1 then timecol end) as timeout
from t
group by id_emp, name, date
```

Can someone please help to achieve for each slots ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data be reasonably well behaved, and every checkin time would always have a closing checkout time, then we can do a simple aggregation query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, IO
                                 ORDER BY COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut)) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN IO = 0 THEN TimeIn END) AS TimeIn,
    MAX(CASE WHEN IO = 1 THEN TimeOut END) AS TimeOut,
    DATEDIFF(minute,
             MAX(CASE WHEN IO = 0 THEN TimeIn END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN IO = 1 THEN TimeOut END)) AS diff_in_minutes
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Name,
    rn
ORDER BY
    ID,
    Name;
```

### Demo

Comment: Should I concatenate it with my above query?

Comment: I don't follow your comment.  Check out the demo and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: I want to get the time ins and outs also for each record.

Comment: How can I differentiate between time in and out on this: `WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, IO
                                 ORDER BY COALESCE(TimeIn, TimeOut)) rn
    FROM yourTable
)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The way I am using `ROW_NUMBER`, all the in times and out times would have their own separate sequence.  Again, I assume your data is well behaved; if not, my answer might have to be updated.